# Run custom calculation for each frame of a transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

As part of a `d3.treemap()`:

In an `svg` element there are nested `groups`. Each group has a `rect` and `text` with a `tspan` as child. 
Like this:

```
<g><rect></rect><text><tspan>Text here</tspan></text></g>
```

The `treemap` is animated and as the values change the size of the rectangles do so as well. It is required that the text in the `tspan` is always centered. The center of the text element is being calculated like this:

```
const calculateCenterOfTextInRectangle = (tspanNode) => {
const rectangleNode = tspanNode.parentElement.previousSibling.previousSibling; // tspan is in text element and 2 nodes above is the rectangle
const centerX = (rectangleNode.getAttribute('width') / 2) - (tspanNode.getComputedTextLength() / 2);
const centerY = (rectangleNode.getAttribute('height') / 2) + (19 / 2); // 19 is the font-size in pixel
return {centerX: centerX,
    centerY: centerY}; };
```

This works fine if the `height` and `width` of the rectangle don't change. But the user can pick a different selection which changes the size of the rectangles and triggers this `d3.transition()`:

```
treemap(root.sum(sum)); // new values
cell.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr('transform', (d) => 'translate(' + d.x0 + ',' + d.y0 + ')')
    .selectAll('rect')
    .attr('width', (d) => d.x1 - d.x0)
    .attr('height', (d) => d.y1 - d.y0);
```

This doesn't change the position of the text which needs to change as well - so as a temporary solution I came up with this:

```
setInterval(
        () => {
            cell.selectAll('tspan')
                .attr('x', function() { return calculateCenterOfTextInRectangle(this).centerX; }) // center x and y. Not using Es6 function because of this context which is the tspan element.
                .attr('y', function() { return calculateCenterOfTextInRectangle(this).centerY; });
        },
        0.1
    );
```

The problem is that the webapplication is less responsive when using the `setInterval` approach. Can I implement the text centering in the `transition` function without using `setInterval`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using `calculateCenterOfTextInRectangle` in your transition is that, even if you call it after setting the new values for the rectangle, you'll get the *initial* values, which is he expected behaviour.

Let's see it in this demo, check the console:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var g = svg.append("g");
var rect = g.append("rect")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 150);

var text = g.append("text")
  .text("foo")
  .attr("x", function() {
    return calculateCenterOfTextInRectangle(this).centerX
  })
  .attr("y", function() {
    return calculateCenterOfTextInRectangle(this).centerY
  });

var gTransition = g.transition()
  .duration(5000);

gTransition.select("rect")
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("height", 40);

gTransition.select("text")
  .attr("x", function() {
    console.log(calculateCenterOfTextInRectangle(this).centerX)
    return calculateCenterOfTextInRectangle(this).centerX
  })
  .attr("y", function() {
    console.log(calculateCenterOfTextInRectangle(this).centerY)
    return calculateCenterOfTextInRectangle(this).centerY
  })

function calculateCenterOfTextInRectangle(tspanNode) {
  const rectangleNode = tspanNode.previousSibling;
  const centerX = (rectangleNode.getAttribute('width') / 2) - (tspanNode.getComputedTextLength() / 2);
  const centerY = (rectangleNode.getAttribute('height') / 2) + (19 / 2); // 19 is the font-size in pixel
  return {
    centerX: centerX,
    centerY: centerY
  };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

There are different solutions here. Probably the less computer-intensive is just passing the new `x` and `y` values to the texts, which you can easily calculate (since you have the new values for the rectangles).

However, if you want to use the transition itself, you can use `tween` (which is way more computer-intensive), like this:

```
transition.select("text")
    .tween("positioning", function() {
        var self = this;
        var rectangleNode = this.previousSibling;
        return function() {
            d3.select(self)
                .attr("x", (rectangleNode.getAttribute('width') / 2) - (self.getComputedTextLength() / 2))
                .attr("y", (rectangleNode.getAttribute('height') / 2) + (19 / 2))
        }
    })
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var g = svg.append("g");
var rect = g.append("rect")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 150);
var text = g.append("text")
  .attr("x", function() {
    return calculateCenterOfTextInRectangle(this).centerX
  })
  .attr("y", function() {
    return calculateCenterOfTextInRectangle(this).centerY
  })
  .text("foo");

var gTransition = g.transition()
  .duration(5000);

gTransition.select("rect")
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("height", 40);

gTransition.select("text")
  .tween("positioning", function() {
    var self = this;
    var rectangleNode = this.previousSibling;
    return function() {
      d3.select(self)
        .attr("x", (rectangleNode.getAttribute('width') / 2) - (self.getComputedTextLength() / 2))
        .attr("y", (rectangleNode.getAttribute('height') / 2) + (19 / 2))
    }
  })

function calculateCenterOfTextInRectangle(tspanNode) {
  const rectangleNode = tspanNode.previousSibling;
  const centerX = (rectangleNode.getAttribute('width') / 2) - (tspanNode.getComputedTextLength() / 2);
  const centerY = (rectangleNode.getAttribute('height') / 2) + (19 / 2); // 19 is the font-size in pixel
  return {
    centerX: centerX,
    centerY: centerY
  };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to select different elements in a single transition by reading the d3 documentation. Thanks for your detailed answer. I use the `selection.tween()` approach and it is working very smoothly.